# Proof Check Lemma 2.2.10 in Tao

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I aim to prove the following.

**Lemma 2.2.10**. Let $a$ be a positive number. Then there exists exactly one natural number $b$ such that $b{+\!+} = a$.

I use the following.

**Definition 2.2.1** (Addition of natural numbers). Let $m$ be a natural number. To add zero to $m$, we define $0 + m := m$. Now suppose inductively that we have defined how to add $n$ to $m$. Then we can add $n{+\!+}$ to $m$ by defining $(n{+\!+}) + m := (n + m){+\!+}$.

**Proposition 2.2.6** (Cancellation law). Let $a, b, c$ be natural numbers such that $a + b = a + c$. Then we have $b = c$.

**Axiom 2.4**. Different natural numbers must have different successors; i.e., if $n, m$ are natural numbers and $n \neq m$, then $n{+\!+} \neq m{+\!+}$. Equivalently, if $n{+\!+} = m{+\!+}$, then we must have $n = m$.

Tao suggested the use of induction, so I am doubting the validity of my proof.

Proof:
Proceed by contradiction. Let us assume we have $2$ differing natural numbers $b$ and $c$, such that $b{+\!+} = a$ and $c{+\!+} = a$. 
Then we have $b{+\!+} = 0 + b{+\!+}$ and $c{+\!+} = 0 + c{+\!+}$ (definition of addition).
So we then have that $0 + b{+\!+} = 0 + c{+\!+}$, but then $b{+\!+} = c{+\!+}$ (Cancellation Law). This is a contradiction due to **Axiom 2.4**.

I am self-studying real analysis, so I want to ensure that I am proceeding correctly.

Comment: You have to prove the existence of such $b$ first (that's why Tao suggests to use induction). Also, once you have $b++=c++$ then $b=c$ by Axiom 2.4.

Comment: @C.I.J. True, I suppose, but I feel like this follows trivially from the way Tao defines induction. We have a base case of $0++$. An induction hypothesis of $n$ existing for $n++$. Clearly, this property holds for $(n++)++$. You are right though, I should mention the existence for completeness. Anything else?

Comment: Apart from that, everything is ok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have proved the uniqueness. Also you need to show the existence of such $b$.

To do that, you need to consider the statement $$P(a)\equiv \text{ there exists a } b \text{ such that } b\!+\!\!+=a \text{ whenever } a\ne0$$
because *$a$ is positive*. Then induct on $a$.

Note that in certain step, the statement is vacuously true.

> We have to prove $$a\ne0\implies\exists b\in\mathbf N,\;\;b\!+\!\!+=a.$$ So, we induct on $a$. The base case $a=0$ is vacuously true. Now suppose inductively that the claim is true for $a$; we need to show the claim for $a\!+\!\!+$, i.e., $b'\!+\!\!+=a\!+\!\!+$ for some natural number $b'$. Thus, by induction hypothesis, we have $b\!+\!\!+=a$. Applying the increment (by Sustitution axiom of equality) we obtain $(b\!+\!\!+)\!+\!\!+=a\!+\!\!+$. Defining $b':=b\!+\!\!+$ the claim follows.

Comment: What do you mean by the base case to be vacuously true, could explain further?

Comment: For the base case $a=0$, we have the implication $A\implies B$ with $A$ false because $0\neq 0$ is false. So the implication is true whatever the thruth value of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof of Cristhian is incomplete. The induction hypothesis does not allow you to assert immediately that there exists a $b$ such that $b{+\!+}=a$ (since the truth-value of $A\implies B$ by itself is not enough to know the truth-value of $B$). Instead, you should consider two different cases in the induction step: 1) $a=0$ and 2) $a\neq0$.

In the first case, $a{+\!+}=0{+\!+}$ and so $b':=0$ is a unique natural number (by Axioms 2.1 and 2.4) such that $b'{+\!+}=a{+\!+}$. In the second case, both the antecedent $a\neq0$ and the conditional $P(a):=(a\neq0\implies\exists!b\in\mathbb N:b{+\!+}=a)$ are true by hypothesis. So, we know there exists a unique natural number $b$ such that $b{+\!+}=a$. This implies that $a{+\!+}=(b{+\!+}){+\!+}$. By Axioms 2.2 (existence) and 2.4 (uniqueness) there exists a unique natural number $b':=b{+\!+}$ such that $b'{+\!+}=a{+\!+}$.

The two cases allow us to state that $P(n)\implies P(n{+\!+})$. Since $P(0)$ is vacuously true, the Proposition follows by induction (Axiom 2.5).

Answer (score 1):

To prove the existence, it will be easy if we consider the contrapositive of above statement

> $\forall a \gt 0 \to \exists b \ (b++ = a)$
> $\longleftrightarrow \forall b (b++ \ne a) \to \exists a (a = 0)$

the RHS implication follows from Axiom 2.3

Answer (score 0):

For those who think "vacuously true" is a little bit difficult to understand, I have constructed a more roundabout proof. It may help you to understand "vacuously true" better.

Proof: Let $P(a)$ be a property of "there exists a natural number $b$ such that $b++ = a$." Let $Q(a)$ be "$a = 0 \vee P(a)$." Obviously, $Q(0)$ is true. Now suppose $Q(a)$ is true, then consider $Q(a++)$. Since Axiom 2.3, $a++ \neq 0$, so we consider $P(a++)$. Trivially, $a$ is the natural number such that $a++ = a++$. So $P(a++)$ is true. Thus $Q(a++)$ is true. Since the mathematical induction, $Q(a)$ is true for every natural number $a$. It is equivalent to saying $P(a)$ is true for every *positive* natural number $a$.