# Cannot prove Lemma 2.2.10 in Tao Analysis 1

Tags: real-analysis, logic, induction

Lemma 2.2.10 in Tao's Analysis 1 asks me to prove:

> *Let a be a positive number. Then there exists exactly one natural number b such that S(b) = a, where S is the successor function*

I attempt to prove *existence only* by induction as suggested.  I am trying to prove that $\forall a(a \ne 0 \Rightarrow \exists b(S(b) = a))$.  The base case $(a = 0)$ is true vacuously.  I then do the inductive step as follows:

1. $a \ne 0 \Rightarrow \exists b(S(b) = a)$    (Assumption 1.)
2. $S(a) \ne 0$  (Assumption 2)
3. ???
4. $\exists b(S(b) = S(a))$
5. $S(a) \ne 0 \Rightarrow\exists b(S(b) = S(a))$
   etc.

I've got no idea what move needs to be made from line 3 onwards?  Can anyone help?

**NOTE**: I realize that someone has already posted a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507288/proof-check-lemma-2-2-10-in-tao) but I do not understand the answer given

Comment: Since not everybody is familiar with the book, can you please explain what $b{+}{+}$ means?

Comment: Seems like he is using C programming notation for the successor function.  I doubt the original text does that.

Comment: Sorry, the book uses b++ to mean S(b), the successor function

Comment: @DanielV, the book uses the ++ notation, which I don't like, so I use S() instead

Comment: Can someone give me any feedback on why this may have been downvoted so I can correct it, thanks

Comment: I assume one has to use the Axioms of the successor function if one wants to prove anything about the successor function. So you should state them here.

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week1.pdf the axioms for the successor function (Peano Axioms)  are Axiom I -V on pages 12 -14.

Comment: One also needs the definition of a positive number, which can be found on page 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the existence only, it turns out you don;t need any of the Axioms!

Here is a proof created in my Fitch prover:

[image]

(Note that the system uses $x,y$ instead of $a,b$, since the latter are considered constants by the system. It also uses $s$ instead of $S$, since the latter would be considered a predicate, rather than a function by the system. Finally, the system has a built in Induction rule ... you can always just add the appropriate instance of the induction scheme, which in this case would be

$$(0 \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists b \ s(b) = 0) \land \forall a ((a \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists b \ s(b) = a) \rightarrow (s(a) \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists b \ s(b) = s(x)))) \rightarrow \forall a (a \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists b \ s(b) = a)$$

If you want to prove that there is a *unique* number $b$ such that $s(b)=a$, then you need to prove:

> $\forall a(a \ne 0 \Rightarrow \exists b(S(b) = a \land \forall c (s(c) = a \rightarrow c = b)))$

For this, we need PA2: $\forall x \forall y (s(x) = s(y) \rightarrow x = y)$

Now, we can either do this all inside an inductive proof:

[image]

Or we can use the earlier established proof as a Lemma:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To prove $\forall a\,(a\neq 0\implies\exists b\,S(b)=a)$ by induction on $a$, you've already done the base case, $a=0$, by observing that the desired statement is vacuously true.  So here goes the induction step.  Assume the statement is true for $a$; we need to prove it for $S(a)$. That is, we need to prove that, if $S(a)\neq0$, then there is some $b$ such that $S(b)=S(a)$.  Well, that's pretty easy: $b=a$ works.

(This induction proof is rather unusual, in that you don't actually need to use the induction hypothesis.)

Answer (score 0):

This theorem can be broken down into 2 parts.  (1) There exists at least 1 $b$ with the stated property and (2) There does not exist more than 1 $b$ with the stated property.

For (1), you can see from considering the structure $S = \{0, 1, 2, \dots\} \cup \{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, \dots\}$ that $S$ satisfies the first order axioms of PA, but not the desired theorem, since $0.5$ doesn't have a predecessor.  So induction is required.  In this case, the inductive property that prevents $S$ from being a model of PA is straightforward, just the property that every nonzero value has a predecessor.

For (2), it turns out that the first order axioms of PA are enough to establish the theorem.  In fact, it follows directly from the axiom $x \ne y \to Sx \ne Sy$.

Comment: I understand that induction is required, but I'm just not sure how to apply it to this particular theorem

Comment: I think you should choose a different name for the set S because S is already used by the successor function.