# Proof of existence of unique successor to a positive number

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, peano-axioms

I am studying Terence Tao's *Analysis I*, 3rd ed., on my own.

I am trying to prove the following lemma:

> **Lemma 2.2.10**. Let $a$ be a positive number. Then there exists exactly one natural number $b$ such that $b\mathrm{++} = a$.

Relevant definitions:

- A positive number is a natural number ($\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$) that is not equal to $0$.
- $b\mathrm{++}$ denotes the successor of $b$, for $b \in \mathbb{N}$.

Axioms related to natural numbers:

1. $0 \in \mathbb{N}$
2. If $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $n\mathrm{++} \in \mathbb{N}$
3. We define $1:= 0\mathrm{++}$, $2:= (0\mathrm{++})\mathrm{++})$, etc.
4. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n\mathrm{++} \neq 0$.
5. If $n\mathrm{++} = m\mathrm{++}$, then $n = m$.
6. Let $P(n)$ be a property regarding $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then suppose both (a) $P(0)$ is true and (b) $P(n)$ is true implies that $P(n\mathrm{++})$ is true for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $P(n)$ is true for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

---

I'm trying to see if there's anything wrong with my proof below of the Lemma for existence. In particular, I'm confused by the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1508250/81560).

*Proof*. For $a = 0$, the statement is vacuously true.

Suppose for some $k$ positive that there exists a $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b\mathrm{++} = k$. Then, it follows that $(b\mathrm{++})\mathrm{++} = k\mathrm{++}$. Since $b \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $c = b\mathrm{++} \in \mathbb{N}$ by an axiom. Hence, there exists a $c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c\mathrm{++} = k\mathrm{++}$.

Comment: Even if it is mathematically correct, an induction proof should not start with a vacuously true statement. This is often done for simplification, but makes it more difficult to graps the step from $0$ to $1$. The fake proof that all numbers are equal is based on such a non-suitable induction start. The base case is vacuously true, but for $2$, we get a false statement.

Comment: Beyond the issue that @Peter just raised, I think we need to know exactly how you've defined the naturals and what results you have at your disposal. The proof can be quick or fairly convoluted otherwise.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with your initial step. You are proving the proposition '$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}(n>0\implies \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: y++=n)$'. Induction on $\mathbb{N}$ starts by checking that this proposition is true for $n=0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I provided what appears to be the most relevant information. Let me know if this still looks incomplete. As was mentioned in the link I provided above, the original exercise suggested using induction.

Comment: Ah great! This should help quite a bit.

Comment: However, the part that is supposed to be the induction step needs to prove the induction step. You need to prove that $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}(P(k)\implies P(k++))$. Your argument doesn't cover all the cases, since as you started you only worked with 'some $k$ positive'. Note that $k>0$ doesn't cover $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. The implication $P(0)\implies P(1)$ is missing.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Oh, so you're saying that I have to look at both the $k = 0$ case and the $k > 0$ case separately... if I'm interpreting you correctly.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Then I would say... if $k$ is $0$, well, that would make the antecedent false (by assumption, we have a positive number which is by definition not $0$), hence we have a vacuously true claim, correct?

Comment: @Clarinetist The antecedent is not false. You just proved in the initial step that $P(0)$ is true. Recall that $P(x)=(x>0\implies \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: y++=x)$.

Comment: Yeah.... although a vacuously true statement can work as a base case, your induction step relies on "some positive $k$" which is *not* covered in your induction step. The proof with a vacuuos should have as induction: not "suppose some positive $k$ that" but "suppose some natural $k$ so that if it is natural that".  Or we could just use $1$ as our base case (assuming we proved there are no positive numbers less than $1$)

Comment: @Clarinetist You can just prove that $P(0)\implies P(1)$ by verifying that $P(1)$ is true with the witness $y=0$ that satisfies $y++=1$. It is incidental that this part of the proof of the induction step looks like you are doing the initial step with $1$. In reality what is being done is splitting the induction step in cases.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy So let me make sure I'm getting this right... you're saying, show $P(0)$ is true (the usual base case), and then say, okay, consider $k = 0$ and $k > 0$. For $k = 0$, use the fact that $y = 0$ implies $y\mathrm{++} = 1$. For $k$ positive, do what I have above. Induction. Done. Do I have that right?

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes. That would verify the hypotheses of the complete induction.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thanks, that's all I need. If you'd like to post an answer, please feel free to and I can mark it.

Comment: You can do that. That way you make sure that you know how to write the complete proof.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I posted an answer. Hope it's right.

Comment: This is strange but in induction when you do the $P(k)\implies P(k++)$ you don't actually *need* $P(k)$ to be true.  If you can prove $P(k++)$ *without* assuming $P(k)$ then it is *still* valid induction!  SO as $k++ = (k)++$ and $k$ we *will* have $P(k++)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(a)$ be the claim
$$P(a): \forall a \text{ positive } \exists b \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } b\mathrm{++} = a\text{.}$$
Consider $P(0)$. By definition $0$ is not positive, so the proof is vacuously true.

Suppose $P(0)$ is true. By definition, $1 = 0\mathrm{++}$, and $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, so there is a $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b\mathrm{++} = 1$. Hence $P(1)$ is true.

Now suppose $P(k)$ is true for for some $k$ positive. Then there exists a $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b\mathrm{++} = k$. Then, it follows that $(b\mathrm{++})\mathrm{++} = k\mathrm{++}$. Since $b \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $c = b\mathrm{++} \in \mathbb{N}$ by an axiom. Hence, there exists a $c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c\mathrm{++} = k\mathrm{++}$.

By induction, existence holds.

Comment: Well, no. The proposition '$0>0\implies \exists b: b++=0$' is true. You cannot deduce '$\exists b: b++0$' from it. To do that you would need, for example, $0>0$ to be true, but it isn't.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I misinterpreted what you mentioned in the comments then. Could you clarify so I can revise my answer?

Comment: One way to write the part of the induction step for $k=0$ is: Since $0++=1$, then $\exists b:b++=1$ is true. Therefore, $P(0)\implies P(1)$ is true.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Oh. So the implication isn't really due to the induction hypothesis there. It's just by definition of $1$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Did an edit. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that could be a proof.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Great, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Axiom $5$ says that if there is a $b$ so that $b++ = k$ then $b$ is unique.  (If $b++ = k$ and $c++ = k$ then $b++ =c++$ and $b = c$).

SInce you base case was not for a positive natural number but a natural number that if it were positive (but wasn't) the prop *would* be true, you can't assume that such a natural number $k$ exists in your induction step.

But you can fix it.

In fact... it's trivial.

If $k$ is a natural number (whether positive or not) then if we let $b =k$ then $b++ =k++$ because... $k++ = k++$ (duh!).  And this is true whether $k++$ is positive or not. (Although it's not possible for $k++$ to *not* be positive.)

And by axiom 5 $b=k$ is unique as $b++ =k++ \implies b=k$.

.....

This is actually kind of weird because in doing the induction step we don't **need** the prior case at all!

=========

Recap:

Base case $k = 0$.  If $0$ is positive (it isn't) then our proposition about positive numbers, no matter what it is, vacuuously holds.

Induction step:  If $k$ is a natural number and it doesn't matter at all whether our proposition holds for $k$ or not,

then there exists a natural $b = k$ so that $b++ = (k++)$. And by Axiom 5 $b$ is unique.

So $P(k++)$ is always true.  (And we don't *need* $P(k) \implies P(k++)$; we have $P(k++)$ is true.  Period.  Always.)

And although that feels very flimsy it is actually valid induction.

======

In hindsight I think the point is Principal of induction is (almost) the principal that we can get to all the naturals by counting but even more fundimental.

$k++$ is a successor to $k$ so every natural number is either $0$ or a successor to a natural number.

Base case: True for $0$.

Induction step:  Whether true or not for $k$ is true for $k++$ (which is the successor of $k$).

So true for all naturals.

And by Axiom 5.  If $b++ = k++$ then $b=k$ and this is number to which the natural number (if it is not $0$) is unique.

The more I repeat it the sounder it feels.

=====

.... Okay.... this is the type of result I like to call "almost an axiom".   That $0$ is the *base* number and that every other natural is a successor that can be "reached" from zero (if we could define  what "reach" means) should *almost* be an axiom.  From that we can derive that induction would have to be true, but then we realize that induction actually *IS* the definition of "can be reached" that we wanted so... induction is the axiom and every natural number is a successor that can be reached from $0$ is a basic proposition.

Induction is merely a formal statement that every natural number can be "reached" by taking a successive string of successors.

Comment: I'll be honest... I was surprised by this result.  (Someone let me know if I'm not using these axioms correctly... it *does* seem flimsy.)  (But then again, I don't know if we need induction.)

Comment: Um.... I *am* assuming the definition of "positive" it that there exists a natural number that has the value as a successor?

Comment: The definition of a positive number is as given in the original post - it is a natural number not equal to $0$.

Comment: Actually, I guess my big worry is to what degree can we *do* induction.  Induction seems to assume that every non-zero natural number is a successor.  (If any natural number *isn't* a successor it'd get overlooked by induction).  But if that is so... okay... this is good!  Principal of induction is how ... I'll edit my post....

Comment: .... Okay.... this is the type of result I like to call "almost an axiom".   That $0$ is the *base* number and that every other natural is a successor that can be "reached" from zero (if we could define  what "reach" means) should *almost* be an axiom.  From that we can derive that induction would have to be true, but then we realize that induction actually *IS* the definition of "can be reached" that we wanted so... induction is the axiom and every natural number is a successor that can be reached from $0$ is a basic proposition.

Comment: @Clarinetist This is not proving existence of the predecessor. The argument is wrong (or tautological since they are assuming that positive means having a predecessor in the naturals). If positive means non-zero natural, then there is something to be proven, but this argument is not its proof.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy where does it fail? If we assume Principal induction, then as $P(k++)$ is always true as ($k++=k++$) and it vacuously true for $0$.  So it is, by the magical incantation of induction, true for all natural numbers.  Now there's a bit of a leap of fate that if we say what about $m$ how is it true for $m$? and we need $m=k++$ and we don't see why that should be... but *as an axiom* the Principal of Induction, implies *by fiat* that for any $m\ne 0$ there must be some $k$ so that $k++=m$. The "by fiat" feels like magic... but that's what axioms are for.

Answer (score 0):

We can tidy it up as thus: to prove each natural $n$ is either $0$ or a successor, we note the base step is trivial and the inductive step works because, regardless of the properties of $k$, $k++$ is a successor.

Comment: So ethereal... but then again basic foundations often are.